# csf/lfd parameter that prevent smtp attacks?

Tags: smtp, csf, lfd

I have a 4~5MB logwatch like this every day! someone like to hack my smtp:

```
....
--------------------- sasl auth daemon Begin ------------------------ 


 SASL Authentications failed 3965 Time(s)
 Service smtp (pam) - 3965 Time(s):
    Realm  - 3959 Time(s):
       User: account - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: admin - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: admin1 - PAM auth error - 147 Time(s):
       User: chris - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: contact - PAM auth error - 6 Time(s):
       User: fax - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: info1 - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: master - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: noname - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: pamela - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: scanner - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: test1 - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
       User: user1 - PAM auth error - 346 Time(s):
    Realm xxxxx.com - 6 Time(s):
       User: contact@xxxxxxx.com - PAM auth error - 6 Time(s):


 **Unmatched Entries**

 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= 
 pam_unix(smtp:auth): check pass; user unknown
.....
```

what parameter should I change to prevent this brute force on smtp? I think I should change a number but do not know which one.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical answer to "how to deal with brute force attacks" like these is to use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). If you're using some sort of web hosting control panel, you may find options related to fail2ban already there.

Comment: so lfd is useless in this case?